# Log4j was not logging data from inside "If else" condition (Java selenium webdriver)

Tags: java, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, log4j, testng.xml

I am facing issue with Log4j. When I run my below test case, it was fine with output and all tests has been passed. But Log4j was not logging properly. It was logging data only from outside of "If else" condition and skipping data from inside "If else" condition.

My test script:

```
package com.LoginPage.Testcase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class LoginPageDDT {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static Logger logger;
    
    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    
    public void setup(String br)
    {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("LoginPage");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("Log4j.properties");
        if(br.equals("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");  
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(br.equals("firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");  
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(br.equals("ie"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");       
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "LoginData")
    
    public void loginTest(String user, String pwd, String exp)
    {
                driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
                
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'FormAuthentication')]")).click();
                
                WebElementtxtEmail=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']"));
                txtEmail.clear();
                txtEmail.sendKeys(user);
                logger.info("user name provided");
                
                WebElementtxtPassword=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']"));
                txtPassword.clear();
                txtPassword.sendKeys(pwd);
                logger.info("passward provided");
                
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(text(),'Login')]")).click();//Login  button
                
                String exp_title="The Internet";
                String act_title=driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println(act_title);
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
                
                if(exp.equals("Valid"))
                {
                    if(exp_title.equals(act_title))
                    {
                        logger.info("Login Passed");
                        Assert.assertTrue(true);
                        
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
                        
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Assert.assertTrue(false);
                        logger.info("Login failed");
                    }
                }
                else if(exp.equals("Invalid"))
                {
                    if(exp_title.equals(act_title))
                    {
                        
                        Assert.assertTrue(false);
                        logger.info("Login passed");
                        
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Assert.assertTrue(true);
                        logger.info("Login failed");
                    }
                }
    }
    
    @DataProvider(name="LoginData")
    public String [][] getData() throws IOException
    {
        String loginData[][]= {
                
                {"tomsmith", "SuperSecretPassword!", "Valied"},
                {"tomsmith", "SuperSecretPasswor!", "Invalied"},
                {"tomsmit", "SuperSecretPassword!", "Invalied"},
                {"tomsmith", "SuperSecretPassword!", "Valied"},
                            };
        
        return loginData;
        }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
    

}
```

My TestNG suite

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="LoginPageTemplateV2">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.LoginPage.Utilities.Reporting" />
    </listeners>


    <test name="LoginPage Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
            <!-- <class name="com.inetbanking.testCases.TC_LoginTest_001" />-->
             <!-- class name="com.inetbanking.testCases.TC_LoginDDT_002" />-->
            <class name="com.LoginPage.Testcase.LoginPageDDT" />

        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

My test log

```
2022-03-26 11:35:17,071 - LoginPage -INFO - user name provided
2022-03-26 11:35:17,656 - LoginPage -INFO - passward provided
2022-03-26 11:35:19,742 - LoginPage -INFO - user name provided
2022-03-26 11:35:19,987 - LoginPage -INFO - passward provided
2022-03-26 11:35:21,978 - LoginPage -INFO - user name provided
2022-03-26 11:35:22,193 - LoginPage -INFO - passward provided
2022-03-26 11:35:23,874 - LoginPage -INFO - user name provided
2022-03-26 11:35:24,045 - LoginPage -INFO - passward provided
```

`("user name provided", "passward provided")` are the logs which is scripted **outside of "If else" condition**; `("Login Passed", "Login Failed")` are the logs which are scripted **inside of "If else" condition** which are not Logging. I tried to change a different versions of Log4j dependencies. But nothing works.

Comment: You could have solved this easily yourself just by logging what is in `exp`, and noticed that it says `Invalied`

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/4420967/james-z , Thanks for your comment. But in my case, I have included also negative test case. If I logging what is in exp, I only able to perform positive test case.

Comment: Oh course you could have logged it. You're already logging the (also misspelled) "passward provided" for all your cases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have made a typo error in getData() method which why the code is not entering the if else block. Replace below code and try.

```
I am Facing issue with Log4j. When I run my below Test case, it was fine with output and all tests has been passed. But Log4j was not Logging properly. It was logging data only from outside of "If else" condition and skipping data from inside "If else" condition.

My Test script:

package com.LoginPage.Testcase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class LoginPageDDT {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static Logger logger;
    
    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    
    public void setup(String br)
    {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("LoginPage");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("Log4j.properties");
        if(br.equals("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");  
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(br.equals("firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");  
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(br.equals("ie"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");       
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "LoginData")
    
    public void loginTest(String user, String pwd, String exp)
    {
                driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
                
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'FormAuthentication')]")).click();
                
                WebElementtxtEmail=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']"));
                txtEmail.clear();
                txtEmail.sendKeys(user);
                logger.info("user name provided");
                
                WebElementtxtPassword=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']"));
                txtPassword.clear();
                txtPassword.sendKeys(pwd);
                logger.info("passward provided");
                
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(text(),'Login')]")).click();//Login  button
                
                String exp_title="The Internet";
                String act_title=driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println(act_title);
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
                
                if(exp.equals("Valid"))
                {
                    if(exp_title.equals(act_title))
                    {
                        logger.info("Login Passed");
                        Assert.assertTrue(true);
                        
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
                        
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Assert.assertTrue(false);
                        logger.info("Login failed");
                    }
                }
                else if(exp.equals("Invalid"))
                {
                    if(exp_title.equals(act_title))
                    {
                        
                        Assert.assertTrue(false);
                        logger.info("Login passed");
                        
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Assert.assertTrue(true);
                        logger.info("Login failed");
                    }
                }
    }
    
    @DataProvider(name="LoginData")
    public String [][] getData() throws IOException
    {
        String loginData[][]= {
                
                {"tomsmith", "SuperSecretPassword!", "Valid"},
                {"tomsmith", "SuperSecretPasswor!", "Invalid"},
                {"tomsmit", "SuperSecretPassword!", "Invalid"},
                {"tomsmith", "SuperSecretPassword!", "Valid"},
                            };
        
        return loginData;
        }
```